# Unable to perform swapping in ArrayList

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a method to swap ArrayList elements,which are string.I have come up with the following method.This gives me an error,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException    at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)     at
>   Alternate_ArrayList.swapPairs(Alternate_ArrayList.java:139)   at
>   Alternate_ArrayList.main(Alternate_ArrayList.java:56)

My method is:

```
  public static List swapPairs(List<String> students)
    {
        String temp="";
        String temp2="";
        if(students.size()%2==0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<students.size()-2;i++)
            {
                temp=students.get(i);
                temp2=students.get(i+1);
                students.add(i,temp2);
                students.add(i+1,temp);



            }
            return  students;
        }
        return  students;
    }
```

My main is:

```
public class Alternate_ArrayList {
public static void main(String args[])
{
List<String> students=new ArrayList<String>();
    students=Arrays.asList("B","R","M","F");
    System.out.println("Sawp pair: " + swapPairs(students));
}
}
```

The 'set (index,object) made the error go away.However, now my first 2 elements get swapped,not the last two though.

Some suggestion would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: you should probably use `set` (replaces) instead of `add` (inserts).

Comment: What do you call this with? Can you please show the whole class?

Comment: Can you point out (with a comment) which line is 139?

Comment: What is the concrete type of the list? It seems like it doesn't implement the add(index, value) method, therefore you get the default behavior of AbstractList. Also - I'm not sure you need this method - it inserts values rather than updates existing ones.

Comment: @MarkW: that won't happen here, because there's no usage of an iterator in this code.

Comment: @All, please see above edited problem

Comment: Arrays.asList returns a fixed size list. It doesn't support insertions. The original ArrayList is being overridden by the new list, so the constructor call can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ArrayList.set(index,Object)** method instead of add to replace value at an index as follows:

```
students.set(i,temp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure on what exactly is your definition of "swap", but if you just want to swap pairs of students, you might want to do something like this:

```
public static List<String> swapPairs(List<String> students)
{
    String temp;
    String temp2;
    if(students.size()%2==0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<students.size();i+=2)
        {
            temp=students.get(i);
            temp2=students.get(i+1);
            students.set(i,temp2);
            students.set(i+1,temp);
        }
    }
    return  students;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I have one question: Why are you iterating through the entire list [for(int i=0;i<students.size();i+=2)]?

Comment: I only did it through students.size()-2

Comment: This swaps pairs of students, that is, it swaps the first (students.get(0)) with the second (students.get(1)), then the third with the fourth... So you have to do an iteration for each 2 students (that's why i is increased by 2 on each iteration). Keep in mind your code expected the list to have a length which is multiple of two, so it will do nothing if the length is not.

Comment: also students.size()-2 will not swap a list of just two items

Answer (score 0):

The list you received in parameter seems to be an immutable list and so, it can't be modified. 
Look at the caller of the method to check your list and fix it.
Or, if you prefer, you can also create a new list based on the one passed as parameter at the beginning of your method:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(students)
```

UPDATE:

In your main method, Arrays.asList() return a fixed-size list. You can't use add() on it. If you just want to swap, use set() instead of add(). If you need to change the size of the list, do as I said at the beginning of my answer and create a new list.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to go into an infinite loop because of add. Try this code and see if it works:

```
public static List swapPairs(List<String> students)
    {
        String temp="";
        String temp2="";
        if(students.size()%2==0)
        {

            //Removed size()-1 to handle lists with two elements and added I=1+2 to swap alternate elements.
            for(int i=0;i<students.size() ;i=i+2)
            {
                temp=students.get(i);
                temp2=students.get(i+1);
                students.set(i,temp2);
                students.set(i+1,temp);



            }
            return  students;
        }
        return  students;
    }
```